# How to get the variable which are in single quotes only in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

How to check if a string is in single or double or no quotes in python3, is there any method/ logic in python to get it or if not we can use a regular expression

For example-

```
Name = "xxx"

Name = 'xxx'
```

Comment: You only have two diffrent quotes so that you cant write quotes marks in strings without the use of escapes. f.x. "i say 'hi' today" will show in a print function as i say 'hi' today

Answer (score 3):

1. You can't have a string in no quotes. It's not a string without quotes (your example would try to load a variable named `xxx`, which could hold anything).
2. After parsing, there is no difference between a single and double-quoted string. It makes a difference on which characters must be escaped, but for your example, `"xxx"` and `'xxx'` are 100% indistinguishable (`"XXX"` could be distinguished from `'xxx'`, but only because the capitalization doesn't match, not because of quotes).